# gst-launch-1.0 two pipelines/sinkfiles

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspbian

I am working on a flying drone that sends live stream from a Raspberry Pi 2 to my computer trough a 3G modem/WI-FI, and the stream is made with this command :

`sudo raspivid -t 999999999 -w 320 -h 240 -fps 20 -rot 270 -b 100000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.103 port=5000`

The stream works very well, but i have a problem, while `raspivid` is running i want to take pictures from 5 to five seconds, and when i am executing this command while running `raspivid` i'm getting this :

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/www/camera# /usr/bin/raspistill -o cam2.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Now what solutions do i have? Another idea is that i use gstream with both `udpsink` and `filesink` to a .avi, but i get error again :

`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link multifilesink0 to filesink0`

What can i do in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the full pipeline you are using when you add multifilesink to it? It would be easier to make a suggestion by seeing that.

Does the raspistill work if raspivid isn't online and working? Maybe there is a limitation of concurrent access here.

Comment: scroll down to @mpr comments, the other guy, there is the full pipeline and the new idea of doing this ...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK only one Raspberry Pi program can grab the camera at a time.  Since you're always streaming live video that precludes you from adding the five second snapshots on the Pi side (unless you write something custom from scratch).

What I'd suggest doing instead is handling the five second snapshots on the receiving side using the same encoded video data you're using for the live stream.  This will ease battery usage on your drone and all the data you need is being sent already.

Comment: for the moment i am using this pipeline `sudo raspivid -t 999999999 -w 320 -h 240 -fps 20 -rot 270 -b 100000 -o - | tee output.h264 | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.103 port=5000` using the ` tee output.h264` command and then try to get images from a video with `time avconv -i output.h264 -s 320x240 -f image2 -q:v 2 video-%03d.jpg` ... still working on this, what do you think about this ideea? also i have to make a photo while filming every 1 second, not 5 ...

Comment: I'd still suggest collecting the still images on the receiver side using the video stream.  Not sure why you'd make a drone perform duplicate tasks that exhaust its resources.

Comment: because i have to make stream and do photos same time, what is so hard to understand? this is what i must do, it will not be "exhaust its resources" ...